# How to install Logitech software on Linux (for G432 HeadPhone -- Micro Not Recognised with In/Out audio Jack)?

Tags: microphone, logitech

- I cannot receive sound from the micro of my *Logitech G432 7.1* Headphone while connected by Audio (In/Out) Jack Socket.

Maybe I could install [Logitech software](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024841293--Downloads-G432-Gaming-Headset)(such as G Hub (?)), to improve the compatibility between Linux and my headphone, but the software are only provided for Windows, or Mac OS, but not for GNU/Linux (Of Course, *wine* does not want to works with G Hub...)

Is there an alternative on Linux to improve my experience with this headphone ?
(Maybe some audio settings could be made with PulseAudio or others as [this article](http://blog.brendel.com/2011/06/wireless-usb-headsets-on-linux-my.html) may suggest.

I discovered a really nice project ([open razer](https://openrazer.github.io/)), that could satisfy my needs, but it concerns *Razer* materials.

NB. This is not really a "vital need", because I can use quite normally this headphone with the USB adapter, but I am still interested. (even if only it is to free a USB port...)

Comment: Any feedback anyone ?